# Location where pip runs from changed to msys after using Nuitka

Tags: python, pip

I used Nuitka with one of my programs, and went to go install a module with pip for something else.
Previously, pip was running from C:\Users\siyua\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages, but after using Nuitka, I noticed that it was now trying to run from C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\pip.exe \ **main**.py.

I tried adding the path to pip to my PATH variable, and that didn't work. So far, the only way I can get pip to run from the original location is if I manually change the directory to the original one. I don't want to do that every time I need to install something.

Is there a way I can reset it to the original location?

Comment: Have you tried editing your PATH environment variable to exclude `C:\msys64\mingw64\bin`?